# django - reset password views issue

Tags: django, passwords, django-urls, django-1.7

I have been unable to solve this issue after spending 3 hours trying and searching SO & Google.

I am trying to set up the reset password function.

Here is my urls:

```
urlpatterns += patterns('', url(r'^reset_password/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset', {'template_name': 'users/reset_password.html', 'email_template_name': 'users/reset_password_email.txt', 'subject_template_name': 'users/reset_password_subject.txt', 'extra_context': {'languages': LANGUAGES, }, }, name='reset_password'), )

urlpatterns += patterns('', url(r'^reset_password_done/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset_done', {'template_name': 'users/reset_password_done.html', 'extra_context': {'languages': LANGUAGES, }, }, name='password_reset_done'), )

urlpatterns += patterns('', url(r'^reset_password_confirm/(?P<uidb64>[0-9A-Za-z_\-]+)/(?P<token>.+)/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset_confirm', {'template_name': 'users/reset_password_confirm.html', 'extra_context': {'languages': LANGUAGES, }, }, name='password_reset_confirm'), )

urlpatterns += patterns('', url(r'^reset_password_complete/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset_complete', {'template_name': 'users/reset_password_complete.html', 'extra_context': {'languages': LANGUAGES, }, }, name='reset_password_complete'), )
```

The reset password emali is sent, but the link in the email causes an error.

This is the link copied from the email sent to the user:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/reset_password_confirm/MQ/455-425cc3d8545fd75d4334/
```

When I place the url in my browser, I get the following error:

[image]

**I just cannot see the error!** I am hoping that someone can point out what I have done wrong.

**EDIT**

After I change the `name='reset_password_complete'` to `name='password_reset_complete'` I get the following error:

[image]

**Any suggestions to solve this issue would be appreciated.**

Comment: You called view `reset_password_complete`. Try to remove name parameter in the url function or rename view to `password_reset_complete`

Comment: user2172884 - thanks but that does not appear to work.

Comment: just made an edit to this suggestion.

Comment: Please show the complete traceback, and paste the text instead of posting a screenshot. It might be useful if you post your template `users/reset_password_confirm.html` as well.

Comment: Thanks, just got it working - not sure why, but your suggestions definately helped!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The url pattern must be named `password_reset_complete`. You currently have `reset_password_complete`.

```
url(r'^reset_password_complete/$',
    'django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset_complete', 
    {
        'template_name': 'users/reset_password_complete.html', 
         'extra_context': {'languages': LANGUAGES, }, 
    }, 
    name='password_reset_complete',
)
```

Comment: Alasdair, thanks, I have just made an edit to the op regarding the change you suggested.

Comment: Alasdair, thanks! Just got it working - not sure why, but your suggestions definately helped!